# Can i add radius button in singlechild scroll view?

Tags: flutter

I am using Stack widget in which I have 2 widgets one is just an image and the other is `Singlechildscrollview`.

I need to add a button on the footer of the screen and fix this (not moveable). Need to be fixed on screen when the `Singlechildscrollview` scroll or not I need to fix this button. I am not sure how can I do this because if I out the button in `Singlechildscrollview`  then it will show only when I scroll. I need to fix when I scroll or not button should appear.

Here is my code:

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: statusBarHeight * 0.8),
          height: height * 0.4,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage(
                'assets/images/place2.jpg',
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: height * 0.3),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(30),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(30)),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.05,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'NYC Food Festival',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.calendar_today,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Color(0xff808080),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: width * 0.02), // give it width
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Sat, May 25, 2020',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(
                              Icons.attach_money,
                              size: 20,
                              color: Color(0xff808080),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: width * 0.02), // give it width
                            Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '25,000 PKR',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xff000000),
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 15),
                                ),
                              ],
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'Snaps',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              CarouselSlider(
                                options: CarouselOptions(
                                  autoPlay: true,
                                  aspectRatio: 2.0,
                                  enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                ),
                                items: imageSliders,
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'About',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                              right: width * 0.03, left: width * 0.03),
                          child: DescriptionTextWidget(
                              text:
                                  "Flutter is Google’s mobile UI framework for crafting high-quality native interfaces on iOS and Android in record time. Flutter works with existing code, is used by developers and organizations around the world, and is free and open source.")
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: width * 0.03),
                        child: Text(
                          'Included',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.02,
                      ),
                      Included(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.01,
                      ),
                      Included(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.01,
                      ),
                      Included(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: height * 0.01,
                      ),




                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
```

Here is the output of current view:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: there are many buttons you can add in flutter. You can try materialbutton,flatbutton,or raisedbutton. Search them up.

Comment: Yes but need to know how can I fix in the footer

Comment: Try Bottom appbar @Shahnaz Raheem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this look with relative ease.

Here is an example:

```
class BottomFadeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Bottom Fade Button"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          // height: 500,
          color: Colors.amberAccent,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text("Hello "),
                      );
                    }),
              ),

             // Bottom Button
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    // color: Color.fromARGB(110, 255, 255, 255),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    ),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Color.fromARGB(30, 255, 255, 255),
                        Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                      end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 100,
                          vertical: 20,
                        ),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          "BUY TICKETS",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        return print("Tap");
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

yes you can add the button in stack and then wrap with align widget with alignment.bottom_center